# How to count number of fields in a table?

Tags: ms-access, vba, field, ms-access-2010

I am trying to count number of fields in a table in Access 2010. Do I need a vb script?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can retrieve the number of fields in a table from the `.Count` property of the `TableDef` `Fields` collection.  Here is an Immediate window example (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>g</kbd> will take you there) ...

```vb
? CurrentDb.TableDefs("tblFoo").Fields.Count
 13
```

If you actually meant the number of rows instead of fields, you can use the `TableDef` `RecordCount` property or `DCount`.

```vb
? CurrentDb.TableDefs("tblFoo").RecordCount
 11 
? DCount("*", "tblFoo")
 11
```

Comment: **@HansUp**, damn I missed that one.  I always forget about working in the Immediate Window

Comment: @Linger Your answer made me question whether the question is about field count or row count, so I provided both.

Comment: Ok, I think I am dumb... where do I run this command in Access?

Comment: You can use Ctrl+g to open the Immediate window and execute those statements there.  But you could use those same techniques in VBA code if you prefer.

Answer (score 4):

Using a query:

```
'To get the record count
SELECT Count(*) FROM MyTable
```

In DAO it would look like:

```
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM MyTable")
rst.MoveLast

'To get the record count
MsgBox ("You have " & rst.RecordCount & " records in this table")

'To get the field count
MsgBox ("You have " & rst.Fields.Count & " fields in this table")
```

***Note***, it is important to perform the `MoveLast` before getting the `RecordCount`.

In ADO it would look like:

```
Set conn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
conn.Provider = "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0"
conn.Open(Server.Mappath("MyDatabaseName.mdb"))

Set rst = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.recordset")
rst.Open "SELECT * FROM MyTable", conn

'To get the record count
If rst.Supports(adApproxPosition) = True Then _
  MsgBox ("You have " & rst.RecordCount & " records in this table")

'To get the field count
MsgBox ("You have " & rst.Fields.Count & " fields in this table")
```

Answer (score 2):

Quick and easy method: Export the table to Excel and highlight row 1 to get number of columns.